# Need help to search a network

Tags: go, networking, tcp

I have a program which I use at work for organising jobs and planning future work. Kind of like a todo list on steroids. At present it runs via a central golang server and users connect through local network to the server to retrieve data. The server gets the IP address of the host machine and saves it to a file on a shared drive and the clients read this file so they know where to connect. I would like to have this done differently so that the clients (also golang servers) each perform a search of the local network upon startup until they find the server and then store its IP address. I am wondering if there is a way to scan a network and ping each IP address until it gets a response from the server machine?

I can get the client machines to perform a 'ping' to a set address and I can expand upon this with a for loop to generate a list of IP address's to 'ping'. It just doesn't seem elegant enough to me and I am wondering if there is a smart way of carrying out a search on the network pinging all machines on a set port until a response is received?

Comment: Use [mDNS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multicast_DNS) and DNS service discovery.

Comment: You can use multicast for this type of thing.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Thank you so much! That was exactly what I was after and wouldn't have found the answer without your feedback. Quick googling and found [this](https://sosedoff.com/2017/09/07/zeroconf.html) which gave me exactly what I was after :)